# How we start all activities with one object of intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I make one object of Intent

Intent I = new Intent(this , Second.class);

Put some data and start second activity

startActivity(i);

In Second.java I get intent

Intent intent = getIntent();

And put some more data , now I want to start 3rd activity without creating second intent.

Any help

Comment: Could you briefly explain why you want to achive that?

Comment: I want to show data of both activities on final activity without using Database or Shared Preferences, can I do this using one object of Intent.

Comment: Use the old Intent with the extras and add your new info's from
Second.class. Then try oldIntent.setClass(YourFinalClass.class); should work for you. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second class you get an Intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Put some data by calling putExtra(name, value) method and set the class for intent

```
intent.setClass(context, class)
```

In first parameter you give `getApplicationContext()` and in second parameter you give class name you want to start and start activity by calling `startActivity(intent)` and pass intent to it.

```
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext, Abc.class);

startActivity(intent);
```